# ¿Login en Laravel 6 con dos tablas?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos tipos de usuarios en mi app, la primera es **users** la cual es la tabla que crea laravel, pero tengo otra que cree yo que  llama **tiendas**, estoy tratando de que en el mismo formulario de login se pueda iniciar sesión como **user** o como **tienda** pero no he podido, he leído que **Auth::attemp()** es el método que se encarga de buscar los datos en una tabla para hacer la validación, pero solo busca los datos dentro de la tabla **users.**

Answer (score 2):

En el archivo config/auth.php tienes un array de guards, puedes crear uno dd la siguiente forma

```
'guards' => [
        'tienda' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'tiendas',
        ],
    ],
```

Luego en providers

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'tiendas' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Tiendas::class,
        ],
    ]
```

Cuando hagas el attempt de Auth, deberas modificar la ruta del formulario del login para que te lleve a un controlador donde utilices una función de login y ahi utiliza el guard

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if ($request->get('type') == 'tienda') {
            if (Auth::guard('tienda')->attempt($credentials)) {
                 return redirect()->to('route.to.dashboard');
            }
        } else {
            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return redirect()->to('route.to.dashboard');
            }
        }
        return redirect()->to(route('login'));
    }
```

Comment: Puedes decirme donde tengo que escribir "Auth::guard('tienda')->attempt($request);"

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para que observes donde utilizar el guard

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu repuesta, pero lo que soluciono mi duda fue ese articulo: https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986